# jQuery datetimepicker destroy not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, datetimepicker

I am trying to destroy a datetimepicker on change of another.

Here is my scenario-

I have two or more datetimepickers in my application. As an example if I change first datetimepicker then it's date is set to `.next()` datetimepicker as minimum setup of date, Hence for all next datetimepickers.

So this is an **ascending** orders of dates, **No date of previous element is greater than next element.**

Here is what I tried-

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(); //initialized datetimepicker for all elements.

$('.datetimepicker').change(function(){
    $(this).next('input.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
       minDate:$(this).val()
    });
});
```

My problem is very clear, It never sets the minimum date for next `.datetimepicker`.

For an instance If the value of first element is `02 Feb 2015` then minimum value of next is also the same.

Hereby, I tried destroying next element first then applied the same-

```
$('.datetimepicker').change(function(){
   $(this).next('input.datetimepicker').destroy();

   $(this).next('input.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
       minDate:$(this).val()
   });
});
```

But it always invokes with the default functionality.

I am using this reference- https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to destroy the object. You can set the minDate on change of the previous element.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker1" />
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker2" />
```

**JS**

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();    
$('.datetimepicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
    var nextElem = $(this).next('input.datetimepicker');
    if (nextElem.length > 0) {
        nextElem.data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date)
    }
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/191/)

Comment: what if someone need really to destroy it, for example if you use it knockout binding handlers???

Comment: Guess one can do the same after destroying. I didn't try with knockout but I tried modifying the above fiddle with destroy and it seems to work[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/8ukrp9m2/1/). Also this is an old answer, they would have updated their plugin now.

Answer (score 2):

You can destroy datetimepicker like this way:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker('remove');
```